# Find source of outdated dependencies indicated by Versions Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

In my Maven project (an aggregate project with child projects) I issue the following command for the [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/):

```bash
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

There are a couple of outdated dependencies I'm not sure where are coming from:

```
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependency Management have newer versions:
[INFO]   biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.annotation ................ 6.4.1 -> 7.0.0
[INFO]   org.mockito:mockito-inline ............................ 4.8.1 -> 5.2.0
```

Unfortunately, try as I might, I can't find which library references these. I've tried the following with the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html), both in the root project and in child projects:

```bash
mvn dependency:tree
```

None of the output mentions `biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.annotation` or `org.mockito:mockito-inline`.

The two suspects are:

- `com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.6.0` or `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.21.1` (for `biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.annotation`)
- `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3` (for `org.mockito:mockito-inline`)

But those are just suspicions based upon the additional dependency management I have in the subprojects where those outdated dependencies show up.

Is there any command I can use to find out which dependency is bringing in the outdated dependencies listed by the Versions Maven Plugin?

Comment: when it says 'in Dependency Management', is there a parent pom that defines dependency versions in  a `<dependencyManagement>` block that aren't actually used by your projects? (tree outputs the versions you use from what I can tell)

Comment: Not in my direct POM. It turns out one of them was coming from the parent POM of a library (my own library hehe). See my answer, which includes the command to find out where the dependencies are being managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on the Maven Users mailing list pointed me to the [Maven Help Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/), which has an [`effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) goal with a [`verbose`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html#verbose) option. I already knew about an effective POM, but I didn't realize the goal had a `verbose` option

```bash
mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true
```

That gives me effective dependency management of the individual dependencies, along with the POM each comes from—even with line numbers.

Epilogue: It turns out `biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.annotation:6.4.1` is coming from `org.apache.logging:logging-parent:10.1.1`. And `org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.1` was getting in because I forgot that one of my own libraries  hadn't been updated to use my newer root POM (which manages the versions of testing libraries).